# Google Cloud Storage upload triggers python app alternatives to Cloud Function

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, event-arc

I'd like to find out what's the best architecture for a python app that gets triggered when a file is uploaded to Google Cloud Storage, does some processing and outputs a file to Google Drive?

I've tried using Cloud Functions but I'm getting a `Function invocation was interrupted. Error: memory limit exceeded.` in the logs.

I've also followed this tutorial [Trigger Cloud Run with events from Eventarc](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-run-events#0) so I know that one way is with EventArc and Cloud Audit logs.

2 questions:

1. What other methods are there since I require higher memory limits?
2. How do I get the bucket name and file name from cloud audit logs? through `protoPayload.resourceName`?

Comment: What type of processing are you using with your Cloud Function (CF)? what is the size of the data your are processing in CF ? have you tried to increase the memory of your CF: you can go up to 8GB

Comment: basically I'm doing some basic curve fitting for csv data and outputting a png image to google drive made with matplotlib. The size of the data would probably be max 12 mb. But thank you, I see now I can up the size of the cloud function but I'm gonna go with pub sub instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use PubSub. You can create a [PubSub notification](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/pubsub-notifications) and create a push subscription to the service that you want.

- Http cloud function
- App Engine
- Cloud Run
- Any HTTP service running somewhere (VM, Kubernetes, on prem,...)

EventArc is mainly a wrapper of this process and can call only Cloud Run service (for now)

Comment: thank you for a concise answer. I found some good resources to implement [GCS to Pub/Sub to Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tutorials/image-processing).